# "Without further ado"

Tags: idiom, phrase-request, phrase, saying

Suppose I have invited some friends for dinner and I want to say something before we eat.
But I don't want to give a long speech.
If I do this in English, I might start my last sentence with "without further ado" and then invite everyone to go get some food and eat.
The Finnish phrase I would use ("pidemmittä puheitta") translates roughly to "without speaking any longer".
Is there a similar phrase in Latin that indicates that the speaker wants to stop speaking and let everyone start doing what they came for?
I am not familiar with any such phrase, and I don't quite know how to look for one in a dictionary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seneca's *Thyestes*, line 705, has *dimissa mora* (as an ablative absolute: 'delay having been abandoned').

**Update:**

Or, even better yet, sticking with Seneca's tragedies, *Medea* line 281 has *quid seris fando moras?* 'Why do you sow delays by speaking?' (And line 54 has *has rumpe iam segnes moras*, 'Now break these sluggish delays.')

Additionally, *Oedipus* line 850 has *veritas odit moras*, 'Truth hates delays'; which could perhaps be adapted to something along the lines of *cenae oderunt moras* or *daps odit moras* – or, better, *esuritio/fames odit moras*.

Answer (score 9):

*Sed haec hactenus* might be a useful phrase.  Cicero ended at least a few of his letters to Atticus with this phrase.  "But enough of these things."